# isEnum() does not recognise java.lang.Enum

Tags: java, enums

`isEnum()` is working absolutely fine for enum defined in java `class` .

To my surprise it if failing for `java.lang.Enum.class.isEnum()`.

Following code produces **true**, **false** as output, however I am expecting **true**, **true**

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(Color.class.isEnum());
            System.out.println(java.lang.Enum.class.isEnum());
        }
    }

    enum Color {
        RED, GREEN, BLUE;
    }
```

Why is `isEnum()` behaving like this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily see in `Enum` source code that `java.lang.Enum` is actually a `class`:

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
        implements Comparable<E>, Serializable {
//...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not check the code, seems they should have hard coded true set for it...:)

Answer (score 5):

The docs of `isEnum()` state:

> Returns true if and only if this class was declared as an enum in the source code.

`java.lang.Enum` is declared as

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>...
```

So, by definition, it's not an enum. Beside this, the implementation of `isEnum()` also gives another hint:

```
public boolean isEnum() {
    // An enum must both directly extend java.lang.Enum and have
    // the ENUM bit set; classes for specialized enum constants
    // don't do the former.
    return (this.getModifiers() & ENUM) != 0 &&
    this.getSuperclass() == java.lang.Enum.class;
}
```

`java.lang.Enum.class` wouldn't pass the last check

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [`isEnum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isEnum()) reads

> Returns true if and only if this class was declared as an enum **in the source code**.

Since `Enum` is declared as a class, it doesn't satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Enum itself doesn't have any enumerated values in it - I'm guessing that's why.  The JLS doesn't seem to be particularly explicit about it - other than stating that "*The direct superclass of an enum type E is Enum*".

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.